# TP-Link wireless adapter suddenly not working on Ubuntu 18.04.6

Tags: drivers, wireless, adapter

Fair warning that I am fairly new to Linux so I need everything explained to me like a child. Apologies in advance for my ignorance.

I recently installed a TP-Link wifi adapter, TL-WN725N. Installing the driver was a full-day operation, with me trying every command I could find online in the hopes that I would eventually get it to work. It did eventually work, but I couldn't tell you how or why, and I could easily have installed something incorrectly by mistake.

The adapter worked perfectly for about three weeks, and suddenly today it doesn't. When I check the devices, it does recognize that a wireless adapter is plugged in, but the adapter is no longer connecting or flashing as it used to. I have no idea why, as it was working fine yesterday. I installed the suggested software and firmware updates, but that hasn't solved the issue.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I can answer why your adapter does not work but, based on your description, I would remove the adapter and see if it lights up or functions on another USB port or on another computer. Also test your USB port, plug a USB thumb drive to see if it opens it. I would also check which driver you installed as the BETA driver may have unknown bugs. There is also a question of which hardware version you have. v1,2, or 3[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGQ6l.png)enter image description here
This info found here:https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wn725n/